# How to not quote empty values with csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using a dictwriter as follows:

```
csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys, delimiter=';', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
```

which gives me the desired output when all keys have non-numeric values:

```
key1;key2;key3
"value1";"value2";"value3"
```

now i have keys without values and the dictwriter quotes the empty strings as well:

```
dic.update(key2=None)

{'key1':'value1', 'key2': None, 'key3':'value3'}

key1;key2;key3
"value1";"";"value3"
```

what i would like to have is:

```
key1;key2;key3
"value1";;"value3"
```

how's that possible? any idea?

Comment: yes, i do not use a quoting when writing the headers with `csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys, delimiter=';')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i wasn't able to find a trivial solution, so i decided to open the existing file and to replace those "" values:

```
text = open(filename, 'r')
text = ''.join([i for i in text]) \
    .replace('""', '')
x = open(filename,'w')
x.writelines(text)
x.close()
```

that gave me the desired output

from:

```
key1;key2;key3
"value1";"";"value3"
```

to:

```
key1;key2;key3
"value1";;"value3"
```

all good.. but.. is there a neater way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL` where you have `None` type in dictionary and use `csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` elsewhere:

```
>>> d = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': None, 'key3': 'value3'}

>>> for k,v in d.items():
    if d[k] is None:
        with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
            w = csv.DictWriter(f, d.keys(), csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            w.writeheader()
            w.writerow(d)
    else:
        with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
            w = csv.DictWriter(f, d.keys(), csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
            w.writeheader()
            w.writerow(d)

Output:

key1,key2,key3
value1,,value3
```

Comment: unfortunately i need to mask string-values with `" "`, so neither MINIMAL or NONE is a solution, sadly.

Comment: that wouldn't help, `csv.dictwriter` writes `'key2':''` value as `""`. i could eventuall read the csv file after writing and replace those `""` ?!

Comment: the problem is, that your output-dict doesn't solve the issue. when i write your output-dict to csv i get the following content: `key1;key2;key3
"value1";"";"value3"` and when I use minimal or none quotes, then it would be an issue that value1 and value3 would have no quotes. do you see the problem?

Comment: beside of that, your for-loop gives me the following error `KeyError: None` when `d` is the Dict.